# How i can integration pmd in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab-ci, integration, pmd

I didn't find any mention of this in the official documentation, but I came across an article where it says that there is a possibility, but it is not described

Does anyone have articles on this topic?
language: Apex
CI: Gitlab SaaS